# error when import to sql from excel with data type TIME in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Is there anyway to import data from excel with time data type sql manager is saying unknown column type

```
Found 4 unknown column type conversion(s)
```

`The package will not be run.`

[image]

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Are you using the Import Wizard in Sql Server Management Studio?

Comment: yes @Shiva Sql Server Management Studio?

Comment: @aw04 SQL server 2012

Answer (score 0):

The **Import Wizard** internally uses `SSIS` for the Data Import. The `Excel connection manager` can only handle a few standard data types and it tries to make a best guess based on the first few rows of the Excel file.

So in this case, try manually mapping the time column from Excel source to a `DateTime` column in your target SQL table.

**STEPS**

- In the **Select Source Tables and Views** dialog of the **Import Wizard**, select your Sheet in **Source** (left column) and the  Target table (right column) in the **Destination** (right column).
- Click **Edit Mappings**.
- Locate the column name for the Excel time column in the **Source** column list, and click the **Type** cell for it (next to destination column name).
- Change it to **DateTime**

Now proceed with the rest of the import.

More Info: [Excel Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141683.aspx)